# Where is the code for the transmitter in System Shock 2

Tags: system-shock-2

On the recreational deck, where are all the pictures I have to check to find the code for the transmitter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code itself is:

> 14106

The pieces are scattered across four art terminals around the level - you'll need to interact with them and cycle through the images on each to find them, though if you know the code, you don't need to bother.

The three terminals are located:

Just west of the main elevator in Recreation A, in a small room on the Northeast corner of the upper level of Recreation A, in the two-level lounge on the southeastern corner of Recreation B, and in the Artechnology store on the upper level of the Mall section of Recreation C.

Comment: Yes, but where exactly are the art terminals?

Comment: @Steinin Updated with reasonably precise locations. It's tough without making a map, which I don't have the tools to do at this time.

Comment: How could I ever reach a result like that when the characters found are: `4`, `10` and `6]` ? Where did the first `1` in `14106` come from?